# Efficiently extracting rows from pandas dataframe in which I have to search for elements in a list

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe is like this:

```
id author
1  ['abc','def','alp']
2  ['akx','xyz','shdj','dhhs']
3  ['abc', 'alp','pqw']
```

For eg, I want to extract all the rows with authors ['abc','alp'].It should extract rows 1 and 3.

Is there any efficient way to do this using python pandas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use sets with list comprehension, for filtering [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
L = ['abc','alp']
df = df[[set(x) >= set(L) for x in df.author]]
print (df)
   id           author
0   1  [abc, def, alp]
2   3  [abc, alp, pqw]
```

**Detail**:

```
print ([set(x) >= set(L) for x in df.author])
[True, False, True]
```

Comment: You should also add = because author's list length may also be 2.